# Ruby build query params for external API integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to integrate [Nomics API](https://nomics.com/docs/#section/Introduction) from whose documentation I learned that all parameters are passed not in the body but as query params, like below:

```
uri = URI("https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=your-key-here&ids=BTC,ETH,XRP&interval=1d,30d&convert=EUR&per-page=100&page=1")
puts Net::HTTP.get(uri)
```

Now I want to build some flexible API client. I'm wondering if there's a clever way to pass this query params in the body as json? E.g. I don't need to pass `api_key` as query params inside the path like here `key=your-key-here&` - it will also work if I pass it as a Bearer token like below:

```
class Api

  API_KEY = 'some_key'

  def get_crypto(id: [])
    client.get("currencies/ticker?&ids:#{id}")
  end

  private

private

def client
  @client =
    Faraday.new(API_ENDPOINT) do |client|
      client.request :url_encoded
      client.response :json, content_type: /\bjson$/
      client.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
      client.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
      client.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      client.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{API_KEY}"
    end
end
end
```

Am I doomed to some intermediate method that will build weird, complicated `query_params` ?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if there's a clever way to pass this query params in the body as json? E.g. I don't need to pass api_key as query params inside the path like here key=your-key-here& - it will also work if I pass it as a Bearer token like below:

It doesn't really have anything to do with being clever but how the API will treat the body. Why do you not just simply try it if you can pass it as json body?

Otherwise I recommend to just use ActiveSupport which implements `Hash#to_params`.

```rb
class Api
  def get_crypto(params = {})
    client.get("currencies/ticker?#{params.to_params}")
  end
end

Api.new.get_crypto(ids: [1,2,3]
# currencies/ticker?ids=1,2,3
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_query.rb#L61-L89